# Add WebAPI project reference in Aspnet Core project

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created one solution with 2 separate projects in Visual Studio 2017

> 1. Asp.net Core Web Application (.Net Framework) with Framework 4.6.2 for Angular 4
> 2. Asp.net Core Web Application (.Net Framework) with Framework 4.6.2 for WebAPI

Project 1 has Project 2 reference so i can call webapi through project 1

My Angular UI project works perfectly fine but I am not able to hit my web api.

Can somebody please help me to know any setting i need to do to call my webapi from project 1

Comment: What do you mean you are "not able to hit" your web api?

Comment: I guess as these 2 are different web projects, they will run on different localhost, port and domain in future. You will need to enable CORS support for web api. Refer my post how to do this here: http://www.siddharthpandey.net/enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-asp-net-web-api-2/

Answer (score 0):

Having two web projects in your solution has no purpose as you are running a frontend library (Angular) in one which really don't need an own .NET project, just a folder in a web project.

A simpler way would be to just have 1 web project which hosts the web API and then add the index.html and the angular files to a folder in that project.

Another solution, which I recommend, would be to run [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) (node) and then communicate with the Web API project build in .NET